# Determine "-mmacosx-version-min" for static libraries (*.a) on OS X?

Tags: macos, binaryfiles, mach-o

Is there any way to determine the minimum version of OS X a static library will work with?

For executable files, the "LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX" load command can be inspected using `otool -l /path/to/binary | grep version` but this information is not present in static archives (".a" files). Presumably because they are not Mach-O binaries...